# QScrollArea resizing QWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QScrollArea, which displays a custom QWidget. Whenever the Scrollbar is displayed, it causes the entire widget to resize. I want some space to be left for the scrollbar, so that the entire widget is not resized. How can this be done?