# Adding scroll bar to a Qwidget

Tags: c++, qt, scroll, widget

I want to add scroll bars to the frame container. the QscrollArea can only take on widget but in my frame I need many wigets

I tried to write a code for the bars after adding a horizantal and vertical one  but It's too hard.Is there any pre-made free code I could use ?

thank you

Comment: How did you try to promote?

Comment: @DYangu right click the widget then promote to then I wrote QScrollArea and add

Comment: So if you are using ui in design mode, why don't you add scroll bars directly from input widgets menu?

Comment: @DYangu I have edited the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QScrollArea` can take any number of widgets - indirectly. The `widget()` can contain any number of child widgets, it can have a layout set, etc. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18704271/1329652).

Comment: thank you that actually solved my problem.I have another question I need to put a lot of plot s and text boxes and tables and I want to chose there place on the grid and size i can't do that with your code because It keep setting the layout automatically do you know how do I proceed after I palce the widget myself in design mode  in order to  make it keep it's place after adding it to the layout? I have around 50 widgets and as the user scrolls he will see more of the widgets sort of like having different pages

Comment: @Georges Without a layout you will be solely responsible for widget placement. That's all. I don't understand what are you asking. Or what kind of answer do you expect? It's not true that layouts are added without a way to remove them. You have full control over what widgets have layouts.

Comment: I am new to programming a user interface and new to qt could you explain to me how I could place widgets manually?Or how to modify the layout?

Comment: @Georges Programmatically: add a new widget instance, parent it properly, then set its geometry. Using Designer: clear the layout from the parent widget. Add child widgets. Move/size them as desired.