# How to add widgets to a QScrollView with Python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt-designer, qt3

I am writing an app that dynamically adds and removes widgets to a [`QScrollView`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/3.3/qscrollview.html#QScrollView). The code below, using Qt3 and python, will give me dynamic widgets, but when I add too many to be seen, no scroll bar appears. It is not yet scrollable. I've put the relevant pieces of code below.

Any answers **must be in Qt3** because my company only uses Qt3. I'm new to programming and Qt in general.

```
PL = parser.Plist()

class EC_Conf_App(QDialog):

def __init__(self,parent = None,name = None,modal = 0,fl = 0):
    QDialog.__init__(self,parent,name,modal,fl)

    self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self)        
    self.scrollArea = QScrollView(self)        
    self.scrollArea.setGeometry(0, 0, 369, 286)            
    self.Form1Layout = QGridLayout(self.scrollArea)        
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea, 0, 0)  

    for item in PL.plist:
        self.section_create(item.name, item.variables)

def section_create(self, name, variables):


    # ADD ROW BUTTON 
    for key, value in sorted(variables.iteritems()):
        if len(value) > 3:  # if there is more than one option for the combobox
            self.addButton = QPushButton(self.scrollArea, name + '_AddButton')


            self.addButton.setText('Add Row')
            self.Form1Layout.addWidget(self.addButton, self.Ay, self.Ax)
            self.addButton.show()                
           self.connect(self.addButton,SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.add_rows)

def add_rows(self):
    self.addButton = self.sender()
    self.addButton.name()
    copy_class = self.addButton.name()
    clean_name = copy_class[:-10]
    for item in PL.plist:
        if item.name == clean_name:
            PL.insert(item.name, item.heading, item.variables)
            self.remove_widgets()
            break

def remove_widgets(self):
    for item in self.widgets:
        item.deleteLater()
        self.Form1Layout.remove(item)             

    self.construct()

def construct(self):
    for item in PL.plist:
        self.section_create(item.name, item.variables)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to use a layout with a `QScrollView` is to set the layout on its `viewport()`, not the view itself. This is [documented](https://doc.qt.io/archives/3.3/qscrollview.html#details).

Replace `self.Form1Layout = QGridLayout(self.scrollArea)` with

```
self.Form1Layout = QGridLayout(self.scrollArea.viewport())
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18703286/1329652) deals with the same problem for Qt4/5.

Comment: Thanks! Now that I've got .viewport() with my layout, and with each widget creation (self.mainLabel = QLabel(self.scrollArea.viewport(), name + '_MainLabel'), I'm still not getting a scroll bar. I know the link you gave addresses that, but I'm having trouble understanding it because it's in C.